# onCreateOptionsMenu is not called

Tags: android, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have simple application.

Here is MyActivity.java

```java
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

And I don't really understand why method `onCreateOptionsMenu` is called on phone and is not called on tablet?

Comment: if the tablet has a menu key you need to use the hardware menu key

Comment: what are the API-levels (android-versions) of your devices? i bet your phone has <11 while your tablet is 11+

Comment: API>=11 display option menu in actionbar. So remove theme from manifest which hide action bar if there.

Comment: emm, looks like this one: Tablet: ASUS Transformer Prime TF201 (Android version: 4.1.1), Phone: Nexus 4 (AV: 4.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is concept called ActionBar from API 11, so option menu is not use for tablet version.

check for ActionBar tutorial.. see below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 6):

If you're using ToolBar:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your activity is extending from Activity class try changing it to AppCompatActivity..